# Remove substring from shell execution result in makefile

Tags: shell, awk, sed, makefile

In my Makefile, I am trying to extract the virtualbox bridge interface IP, I manage to get it to store the output from the command and echo it, however it contains unwanted characters: "Value: " I only want the IP, I have tried appeding an awk pipe after the VBoxManageCommand but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

```
$(eval VB_IP := "$(shell VBoxManage guestproperty get machinename "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP")")

@echo $(VB_IP) ### This gives: Value: 10.224.199.19

docker-machine ssh oasis "sed '/--label provider=virtualbox/a --insecure_registry $(VB_IP):5000' /var/lib/boot2docker/profile"  ###This makes use of the extracted ip
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a pipe to the command should work:

```
test:
    $(eval VB_IP := $(shell echo Value: 10.224.199.19 | cut -f2 -d:))
    echo $(VB_IP)
```

Or you can use `$(subst FROM,TO,TEXT)` instead of shelling out:

```
    $(eval VB_IP := $(subst Value:,,$(shell echo Value: 10.224.199.19 )))
```

Comment: $(eval VB_IP1 := "$(shell VBoxManage guestproperty get machinename "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP")");
$(eval VB_IP := $(shell echo $(VB_IP1) | cut -f2 -d:))
?

Comment: @DavidKarlsson: I used `echo` because `VBoxManage` doesn't return the same output on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

We may have to try some experiments before we find a solution that works for you. Be aware that things work differently inside and outside rules. Try this, not inside any rule, and tell us the result:

```
VB_IP := $(word 2, $(shell VBoxManage guestproperty get machinename "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP"))
$(info the first result is $(VB_IP))
```

You can also try this inside a rule, and tell us the result:

```
somerule:
    VBoxManage guestproperty get machinename "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP" | cut -f2 -d:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, this is what ended up working for us:

```
# Update the docker-machine daemon with the insecure_registry from the brigded interface on virtualbox
$(eval VB_IP_ := "$(shell VBoxManage guestproperty get machinename "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP")")
$(eval VB_IP := $(shell echo $(VB_IP_) | sed 's/[^ ]* //' ))

@echo Adding private docker repo: registry: $(VB_IP)
docker-machine ssh oasis "sed -i '' '/--label provider=virtualbox/a --insecure_registry $(VB_IP):5000' /var/lib/boot2docker/profile"
```